# How to include BSD licensed component in my project

Tags: licensing, bsd-license

I want to use a software which is licensed under the BSD, in my project.

I come up with two ways.

1. I create a directory for this component and copypaste the original LICENSE.txt file in this directory, and create a LICENSE.txt file for the whole system in the project directory.
2. I create only one LICENSE.txt in the main directory and describe which component is under what license.

Would you tell me the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSD license says

> ...
>   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
>   ...

So the full license text must be available *somewhere*. The license does not state where to put the text or how to name the files containing it, or that there needs to be a file containing the text exclusively. So if by #2 you mean just to name the license in that file, that would be not enough. But if you mean "copy-pasting the full text", then this would be enough. #1 will be probably easier, though.